# How to make horizontal line (<hr>) in HTML span through all page width

Tags: html, web

I have the following HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>

        <h1>My Great Web</h1>
        <FONT SIZE = "5">
        <ol>
            <li> Foo. </li>
            <li> Bar. </li>
        <ol>
        </FONT>

        <br>
        <hr style="width: 100%"/>


       </body>
    </html>
```

Which produce the following figure.
[image]

Notice that the horizontal line doesn't  extend fully to the left. How can I do that?

Comment: Close your `<ol>` => `</ol>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to close your **`<ol>`**

```
 <ol>
   <li> Foo. </li>
   <li> Bar. </li>
 </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

The font tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.
The font element is deprecated in HTML 4.01.

It might display poorly on some browsers

```
<html>
    <body>

    <h1>My Great Web</h1>

   <div style="font-size:12px;">
    <ol>
        <li> Foo. </li>
        <li> Bar. </li>
    </ol>
    </div>

    <br>
    <hr/>


   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Notice **`<ol>`** is closed  at the end **`</ol>`**

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0 ;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        .container {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
        <body>

            <div class="container">
                <h1>My Great Web</h1>
                    <div class="list">
                       <ol>
                            <li> Foo. </li>
                            <li> Bar. </li>
                        <ol>
                    </div>

                <br />

            </div>

                <hr />

       </body>
    </html>
```